# How to compute the first eigenvalue of hyperbolic space ${H^2}$and ${H^n}$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes

How to compute the first eigenvalue of hyperbolic space ${H^2}$and ${H^n}$?

Answer (score 1):

Of which operator? The Laplacian? If so it is related to the right regular representation of Sl(n,R) or rather to the unramified, tempered, unitary reps. The spectrum is continuous and [1/4, \infty) for n =2. The situation is similar in higher rank, but 1/4 has to be replaced by something else (I don't recall what exactly).
In fact, the eigenvectors can be written down explicitly in all cases.